# Ratio, proportion and variation problem

Tags: linear-algebra

There is a certain number of apples, guavas and oranges in basket. The number of each variety is more than one. The ratio of the number of apples to the number of guavas is equal to the ratio of number of guavas to the number of oranges.If the total number of fruits are 61, the find the number of guavas?

1) 16
2) 20
3) 25
4) 1

If the number of guavas is 21, then which of the following can be the total number of fruits in the basket?

1) 63
2) 89
3) 101
4) 117

I tried a lot of ways but I still don't get the answer. Everything seems vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the following information:

1. $a\cdot o=g^2$ (from that ratio)
2. $a,o,g$ are integers $>1$
3. $a,o,g$ are all $<61$
4. $a+o+g=61$

where $a,o,g$ are numbers of apples, oranges and guavas respectively.

You are given $4$ possible values for $g$, plug each one of them into the above statements number 1 and 4. For each value of $g$, you'll obtain - from 1 and 4 - $a+o=...$ and $a\cdot o=...$ which represents the quadratic equation $x^2-(a+o)x+a\cdot o=0$ in $a$ and $o$. Solve it and if you get values that satisfy points 2 and 3 as well, you've got the correct values.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: gee thanks, i had actually tried the hit and trial for the 2nd question, but i may have messed it up somewhere. Now, i did it again and i got it.

Comment: @SumanSahu If the answer helped, please consider accepting it. Thank you!